# How can I insert sequential values from an array into another mapped array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I'm having issues with a component I'm playing with.

I have an array of data that I am successfully mapping into a component. I have another array that contains the visual properties I wish to pass in as props. For example, I'd like the first returned to be red, the next blue, the last green and then repeat the sequence. How might I do this?

I've had a crack at it but you will immediately see why my solution hasn't worked. I understand why this hasn't worked but I'm not sure what to try next.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
const colorsList = ["red", 'blue', "green"]
console.log(colorsList)

const IndustriesPage = ({data}) => (
  <Layout>
        <HeroInternal
          title="Industries"
        />
        <GridBlock>
          {data.allContentfulPageCaseStudy.edges.map(function(target){
            return(
                <TextLinkModule
                  linkTitle = {target.node.industry}
                  titleModifier = 'textLinkModule__title--small'
                  backgroundColor = {colorsList.map(function(target){
                    return(
                       target,
                       console.log(target)
                    )
                  }
                  )}
                  linkDestination = {`industries/${target.node.industry}`.split(' ').join('-').split('&').join('and').toLowerCase()}
                  // backgroundImage = {target.node.linkBackgroundImage.fluid.src}
                /> 
              )
            })
          }
        </GridBlock>
        <ContactUsBlock></ContactUsBlock>
  </Layout>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns the value and the index of each member of the array. You can use the index of each `edge` to return a single value from the `colorsList` array.

```
data.allContentfulPageCaseStudy.edges.map(function(target, idx){
...
backgroundColor = { colorsList[idx % colorsList.length] }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked out a treat. Quick question though. How is that looping through the indexes? When I looked at it I expected it to max out at the third item in the colorList array.

Comment: The modulus operator `%` returns a remainder. So `0 % 3 = 0`, `1 % 3 = 1`, `2 % 3 = 2`, `3 % 3 = 0`, `4 % 3 = 1`, etc, etc.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators